# Easy condition on a matrix $A$ such that $Au\geq 0$ for all vectors $u\geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

A rather easy question, but my brain stopped working. I have a matrix $A$ that depends on various parameters in a non-trivial way. What would be a simple-to-check conditions on $A$ so that $Au\geq 0$ for any vector $u\geq 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A necessary and sufficient condition is that all entries of $A$ are $\ge 0$.